# Laravel 5.1 - Trending Posts - Query on relationship count with timestamp condition of pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.1 for a CMS development. I have a simple structure of posts, users and users can like posts.

I want to list the trending posts (posts with most likes in last 1 week in desc order). Posts and Users have many-to many relationship and use a pivot table for relationship.

Posts Model has

```php
public function likedby()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_like_post')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

User Model has

```php
public function likes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Post','user_like_post')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

How can I write eloquent query so I receive the trending post. I need to use the timestamp of the pivot table which I find difficult to use.

This is what I tried but it used 'created_at' of post table and not of pivot table.

```php
$trending = Post::with('likedby')->get()
    ->sortByDesc(function ($post){
        $one_week_ago = Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1); 
        return $post->likedby
            ->where('created_at','>=',$one_week_ago)
            ->count();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain an eager load within the `with` method, however this would still load all the posts but only eager load the likedby relationship when it is less than one week old. This is probably not the behaviour you want, but worth mentioning.

```php
Post::with(['likedby' => function($query) {

    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1));

}])->get();
```

To only load posts that have been liked within the last week, you would be best served by the `whereHas` method. This will provide you with a list of posts that have had likes placed on them within the last week.

```php
Post::whereHas('likedby', function ($query) {

    $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1));

})->get();
```

Comment: I think I need the first one but it is giving me an error - "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous" - it is unable to understand which 'created_at' it should be using.

Comment: That's strange, the closure uses only the relationship query. Are you doing anything else in the main `Post` query that could be doing that?

Comment: I solved it by putting 'user_like_post.created_at' in where clause to specify which created_at to be used. Thanks.

Comment: I am now facing another problem, the count of likes which I am getting is for the last week only. I want to show the count of all likes and not just 1 week (I want that only for sorting purpose). Any idea, how to get all likes count?